# Redirecting ids in permalink using regex with exceptions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some old urls to new ones, the old ones had "-id" at the end of the url and basically I want to remove that. However, while I was able to do that, I have a bunch of articles that have "years" at the end of the links thus redirecting them aswell, creating a loop.

So far, my code .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-(\d+){3,}/$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm not an expert in regex, I barely started to learn it but I want to add some exceptions to this rule, namely years. It will be ok if I can add just (2010|2011|2012) etc...problem is, I don't know how can I do that and time is not on my side, Google wise :)

Thanks!

Comment: can youi provide few examples of current urls and what they should redirect to?

Comment: www.example.com/article-37128/ to www.example.com/article/ 
- this currently works, given the rewriterule I posted above.

However, if I have 

         www.example.com/article-2019/ i don't want to redirect it

Basically, I want to keep the above rule but add a string of exceptions in years

Comment: At the moment, I manage to do this and it seems to work

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-(?!2015|2016|2017|2018|2019)(\d+){3,}/$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

I'm still not sure if I did something wrong here, I only tested it with 4 distinct links

Comment: I've added the exception string as an interval and it seems to work

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-(?!19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050)(\d+){3,}/$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L] - this excempts years from 1950 to 2050

Comment: If you want to capture 3 or more digits in the group you could repeat the digits instead of the group `(\d{3,})` If you only want to match them, use `\d{3,}`

Answer (score 0):

I've added this exception string as an interval and it seems to work

```
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-(?!19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050)(\d+){3,}/$ example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will match any group of 3 digits or more with the exception of 1950 to 2050